# Grsecurity resource oversteps

Tags: grsecurity

Can anybody explain what this kind of messages in dmesg really mean, or point me to some documentation? I have failed to find non-prehistoric info about dealing with such events.

Sometimes programs seem to work just fine (both examples here) and sometimes they crash. With VirtualBox whole screen freeze (I was able to shutdown my system using the hardware power button.).

```
grsec: denied resource overstep by requesting 21 for RLIMIT_NICE against limit 0 for /usr/bin/xinit[xinit:1814] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /bin/bash[bash:1798] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000

grsec: denied resource overstep by requesting 135168 for RLIMIT_MEMLOCK against limit 65536 for /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox[Media Audio:2540] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /bin/bash[bash:2128] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000
```

My system is x86_64 hardened Gentoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your applications are requesting more resources than is allowed by the limits set in your system. These limits are set in: `/etc/security/limits.conf` (on Debian, at least).

You can also print current limits using:

```
ulimit -a
```

This is what I have in my `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*       -   memlock      256
*       -   nice        -20
```

After changing the limits, you will probably have to log out, or maybe restart for the new values to take effect.